# Save Members in a different database

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to save members in a different database? (I'm talking about the whole member's tables not member properties)

The reason for me asking this is to not worry about members data during content freeze implementation and parallel website migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make your own implementation of a `MembershipProvider` and replace this with the build-in membership provider in the `web.config`.

However, I would rather review your website upgrade process to avoid a "content" freeze. E.g. if you use the [Umbraco Cloud](https://umbraco.com/pricing/) offering, you can push your changes online to upgrade a website while maintaining your content).
Also packages like Umbraco [courrier](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/umbraco-courier/), Umbraco [Deploy](https://umbraco.com/blog/courier-for-content-drag-drop-deploy/), [chauffeur](http://skrift.io/articles/archive/automating-your-umbraco-deployments/) and [USync](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync) allow you to rule out a "content freeze".

Comment: Thanks @dampee, needed someone to confirm that idea for me. :) and thanks also for the advice on how to rule out content freeze.